# cannot start node manager

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

When I try to start node manager I am getting below error. I am getting this error on remote machine. By the way node manager is running on my local machine without any problem. Both machines have same configuration. Is there any idea?

```
<SEVERE> <Fatal error in node manager server>
weblogic.nodemanager.common.ConfigException: Unknown key store identity alias or not a key entry alias: DemoIdentity
at weblogic.nodemanager.server.SSLConfig.loadKeyStoreConfig(SSLConfig.java:175)
at weblogic.nodemanager.server.SSLConfig.<init>(SSLConfig.java:100)
at weblogic.nodemanager.server.NMServer.init(NMServer.java:185)
at weblogic.nodemanager.server.NMServer.<init>(NMServer.java:147)
at weblogic.nodemanager.server.NMServer.main(NMServer.java:353)
at weblogic.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:31)
```

Answer (score 11):

You'll want to go look at the `wlserver_10.3/common/nodemanager/nodemanager.properties` file.

It sounds like your domain isn't set up to use a custom trust store or key store so it defaults to using the "Demo" identity.

In that properties file, verify that

`ListenPort=5556`

`SecureListener=false`

You may also want to login to your admin console and verify that all of the settings here are correct:

`Environments->Machines-> <your machine name> -> Configuration-> NodeManager`

You may want to use `Plain` instead of `SSL`.

If you do want to use SSL, I would recommend checking out a tutorial like the following:

http://jvzoggel.wordpress.com/2011/12/16/configuring-ssl-for-oracle-weblogic-and-ofmw/

Comment: I have posted a related question @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52555078/what-is-the-difference-between-a-weblogic-servers-node-manager-start-script-l If possible, please answer.

Answer (score 0):

Old Question. For future users.

It could not able to find the alias in the keystore specified.

Unknown key store identity alias or not a key entry alias: DemoIdentity.

In the `nodemanager.properties` check the following lines

```
CustomIdentityKeyStoreFileName=<path_file>/kesytore.jks
CustomIdentityAlias=<AliasName>
```

I hope you have given  as `DemoIdentity` and it couldnt find the alias in the `keystore.jks` file.

Make sure you have given correct alias or correct jks file .
To know the list of alias in the jks file

```
keytool -list -keystore <path_file>/kesytore.jks
```